# "How does it compares"

Tags: sentence, modal-verbs

I understand it should be

> How does it compare

because the do has stole the s, but what is the reasoning behind it? I don't want to make the same mistake twice, so I feel I need to understand the reasoning.

Comment: [smile]But it **does** compare, doesn't it?[/smile]

Comment: @smirkingman yes, it kind of does ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because, as with *can* or *should*, *do* is a modal verb, and as such it is [always followed by a verb in its basic form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verb#Syntax): basic form being the verb without the introducing *to*.

Answer (score 1):

Compare can be transitive or intransitive.

Transitive, identifying differences:

> John compared the two books and choose the larger

Intransitive, be comparable

> The larger book just didn't compare with the little one